# Trying to insert into MS Access from VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection

```
Sub ButtonInsertL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonInsertL.Click

    Try
        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Data Source='C:\Users\USER\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\GISProject\GISProject\Database.accdb';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert Into location (locN, type, name, address, City, X, y, streetID) Values (" & Integer.Parse(TextBoxlocN.Text) &
                                               ", '" & TextBoxtype.Text & "', '" & TextBoxname.Text & "','" & TextBoxaddress.Text &
                                               "',  '" & TextBoxCity.Text & "', " & Integer.Parse(TextBoxX.Text) & ", " & Integer.Parse(TextBoxy.Text) &
                                               ", '" & TextBoxstreetID.Text & "')", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        ' Console.WriteLine("peran ar")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: its not giving any errors when i start debugging however when i click insert button to add the data it is not adding in my db and it is crashing

Comment: Is streetID a number or a string?

Answer (score 0):

the field "name" could be causing an issue as it is confused as a reserved word with OLEDb. You can wrap that in [] to overrides this or rename the field in the database.

You're not receiving any errors because you're burying the exception in the try...catch block. You should at the very least log or display ex.message so that you can see what exception you receive.

Also, if you're new to all this. Take the time to learn to use parameterized statements. Not only is it a more secure way of sending commands to the database, it alleviates a lot of problems with knowing when to wrap values inside #'s or '

EDIT:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert Into location (locN, type, name, address, City, X, y, streetID) Values (" & Integer.Parse(TextBoxlocN.Text) &
                                           ", '" & TextBoxtype.Text & "', '" & TextBoxname.Text & "','" & TextBoxaddress.Text &
                                           "',  '" & TextBoxCity.Text & "', " & Integer.Parse(TextBoxX.Text) & ", " & Integer.Parse(TextBoxy.Text) &
                                           ", '" & TextBoxstreetID.Text & "')", con)
```

Looks so much better like this and is more secure

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert Into location (locN, type, name, address, City, X, y, streetID) Values (@loc, @type, @name, @addr, @city, @x, @y, @streetID)
```

Now before you can execute this you need to define what each parameter represents. To do this you use the parameters collection to add them with their values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", Integer.Parse(TextBoxlocN.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", TextBoxtype.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBoxname.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr", TextBoxAddress.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBoxCity.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", Integer.Parse(TextBoxX.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", Integer.Parse(TextBoxy.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetID", TextBoxstreetID.Text)
```

Now that you have defined what each parameter is, you can open the connection and execute the statement.

Keep in mind that with OLEDB, you do not really have such a thing as named parameters. They are basically just placeholders so you MUST add the parameters in the order they appear in your statement.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

Comment: this is what i get when i click the insert button

Comment: Your connection string is incorrect. You need to tell the connection the proper information. Check out ConnectionStrings.Com for an example of what that should look like. Depending on what version of Access you might either need the ACE.OLEDB or the Jet.Oledb4.0 provider.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you are writing queries for a command object there should be no string concatenation (and it should be easy to read - see my [demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-53ce3eb1/sourcecode?fileId=145755&pathId=258937059)), parameters should be used. If you have no control over field names then wrap each field name in brackets e.g. [name] for example. Lastly in the catch go with Exception, surely not SqlException when using OleDb. Conceptually speaking except for wraping field names [the following demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-new-records-into-53ce3eb1/sourcecode?fileId=145755&pathId=258937059) shows the concepts I spoke of Your code need not be that elaborate but the core concept of no string concatenation and parameters. Note how [xml literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are used which keeps the query easy to read.